# Connecting mesh and armature when rigging a posed model (Make Armature and Object Back to T pose)

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

Im pretty new to Blender. I have a 3D model which is already in a specific pose that i want to rig for animation. Since i dont feel like manually somehow fiddling the meshes back to a T or A pose before rigging, i created the armature and bones as best as i can along the posed joints. The legs and arms are connected via keep offset to the hip/spine bones. The problem is, when i try to connect the mesh surrounding it with the armature so it responds to its movement (which it does not yet) with:

(Object mode)

1. Select mesh
2. Shift select armature
3. Ctrl + P
4. Choose "With automatic weights"

something odd happens. The mesh just simply pops away and is somewhere rotated and at a larger size in the room far away from the armature/skeleton. I expected the automatic one not working too well out of the box, but i dont get what is happening. Am i doing this wrong?

Im using Blender 2.93, if that is relevant.

Comment: have you applied scale to the mesh?

Comment: When you parent your object to the armature, it doesn't take into account the pose you've set, it takes into account the armature's Rest pose, so what you see is the deformation of the object by the pose of your armature, and if you bring your armature to its Rest pose it will move back the object to its own rest pose, except it still won't be correct. Maybe you should duplicate the object Armature modifier, disable the copy, use the original one to move the object back to a T pose, apply this modifier, activate the copy.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes, i did use Ctrl + A and applied Scale & Rotation if that is what you mean. Sorry im a noob!

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for your comment! I have to admit that some parts of it are going over my head a bit currently. So is rigging an already posing model that bad? Kinda sucks if the mesh you get already is posing. "Maybe you should duplicate the object Armature modifier" okay i am seeing now that some kind of modifier is being applied to the mesh, but i am not entirely sure i can follow. The mesh is like "laying on its back", 500% times bigger and like a mile away from the armature after applying the parent relationship.

Comment: please share your file (modify it a bit if needed, then upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: oh ok it will be easier that I thought, actually your object is already parented to another object, so as soon as you parent it to another object (the armature) it will come back to its previous position and scale, the one before the first parent. So what you need to do is first unparent with the Keep Transformation (Alt P > Clear and Keep Transformation), then parent to the armature. Also maybe delete your message with the pasteall link if this model is yours or not copyright free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object is already parented to an object, so as soon as you parent it to another object (the armature) it will come back to its previous position and scale, the ones before the first parentage. So what you need to do is first unparent with the *Keep Transformation* option (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*), then parent to the armature.

Now to bring your object back to a rest pose:

- Parent the object to the armature *With Automatic Weights*
- Switch the armature to *Pose* mode and create a T pose
- Apply the Armature modifier of the object
- Switch the armature to *Pose* mode, select all the bones and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Pose as Rest Pose*
- Reparent the object to the armature, this time with the *Armature Deform* option

Comment: Insane, that was the correct answer. I hope to one day understand these things as well as you! Thank you very much.